# C Infinite loop after deleting binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, infinite-loop

I've implemented a function that deletes the tree node along with its subtrees like this:

```
void DeleteTree(BTreeNode * bt){
    if(bt == NULL)
        return;

    DeleteTree(bt->left);
    DeleteTree(bt->right);

    printf("del tree data: %d \n", bt->data);
    free(bt);
}
```

And then I have another function that traverses the tree:

```
void PreorderTraverse(BTreeNode * bt, VisitFuncPtr action){
    if(bt == NULL)
        return;

    action(bt->data);
    PreorderTraverse(bt->left, action);
    PreorderTraverse(bt->right, action);
}
```

Here, the parameter "action" is a function pointer that takes node's data as an argument and has void return type, used to call for another function that prints the data that the node has.

Here is my main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "BinaryTree.h"

void ShowIntData(int data){
    printf("%d ", data);
}

int main(){
    BTreeNode * bt1 = MakeBTreeNode();
    BTreeNode * bt2 = MakeBTreeNode();
    BTreeNode * bt3 = MakeBTreeNode();
    BTreeNode * bt4 = MakeBTreeNode();
    BTreeNode * bt5 = MakeBTreeNode();
    BTreeNode * bt6 = MakeBTreeNode();

    SetData(bt1, 1);
    SetData(bt2, 2);
    SetData(bt3, 3);
    SetData(bt4, 4);
    SetData(bt5, 5);
    SetData(bt6, 6);

    MakeLeftSubTree(bt1, bt2);
    MakeRightSubTree(bt1, bt3);
    MakeLeftSubTree(bt2, bt4);
    MakeRightSubTree(bt2, bt5);
    MakeRightSubTree(bt3, bt6);

    PreorderTraverse(bt1, ShowIntData);
    printf("\n");
    DeleteTree(bt3);
    PreorderTraverse(bt1, ShowIntData);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, after DeleteTree, when PreorderTraverse is called again, the program falls into an infinite loop, printing out some trash values. Can you please explain why is it happening? For your reference, I'll show you BinaryTree.h and BinaryTree.c below for your reference.

BinaryTree.h

```
#ifndef __BINARY_TREE_H__
#define __BINARY_TREE_H__

typedef int BTData;

typedef struct _bTreeNode{
    BTData data;
    struct _bTreeNode * left;
    struct _bTreeNode * right;
} BTreeNode;

BTreeNode * MakeBTreeNode(void);
BTData GetData(BTreeNode * bt);
void SetData(BTreeNode * bt, BTData data);

BTreeNode * GetLeftSubTree(BTreeNode * bt);
BTreeNode * GetRightSubTree(BTreeNode * bt);

void MakeLeftSubTree(BTreeNode * main, BTreeNode * sub);
void MakeRightSubTree(BTreeNode * main, BTreeNode * sub);

typedef void VisitFuncPtr(BTData data);

void PreorderTraverse(BTreeNode * bt, VisitFuncPtr action);
void InorderTraverse(BTreeNode * bt, VisitFuncPtr action);
void PostorderTraverse(BTreeNode * bt, VisitFuncPtr action);

void DeleteTree(BTreeNode * bt);

#endif // __BINARY_TREE_H__
```

BinaryTree.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "BinaryTree.h"

BTreeNode * MakeBTreeNode(void){
    BTreeNode * nd = (BTreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(BTreeNode));

    nd->left = NULL;
    nd->right = NULL;
    return nd;
}

BTData GetData(BTreeNode * bt){
    return bt->data;
}

void SetData(BTreeNode * bt, BTData data){
    bt->data = data;
}

BTreeNode * GetLeftSubTree(BTreeNode * bt){
    return bt->left;
}

BTreeNode * GetRightSubTree(BTreeNode * bt){
    return bt->right;
}

void MakeLeftSubTree(BTreeNode * main, BTreeNode * sub){
    if(main->left != NULL)
        free(main->left);

    main->left = sub;
}

void MakeRightSubTree(BTreeNode * main, BTreeNode * sub){
    if(main->right != NULL)
        (main->right);

    main->right = sub;
}

void PreorderTraverse(BTreeNode * bt, VisitFuncPtr action){
    if(bt == NULL)
        return;

    action(bt->data);
    PreorderTraverse(bt->left, action);
    PreorderTraverse(bt->right, action);
}

void DeleteTree(BTreeNode * bt){
    if(bt == NULL)
        return;

    DeleteTree(bt->left);
    DeleteTree(bt->right);

    printf("del tree data: %d \n", bt->data);
    free(bt);
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger....

Comment: I used the debugger and it says the error happens at the function ShowIntData, but if the memory for the tree node is freed, shouldn't the parameter bt in PreorderTraverse be equal to NULL and escape the function?

Comment: See my answer. free doesn't set the passed pointer to `NULL` automatically. You should see it with your debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[free](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free) does not set passed pointer to `NULL`.

Calling `PreorderTraverse` after deletion invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)  because the function will try to dereference freed dynamic memory.

Comment: That was the reason... Thanks a lot! Then if I want to set the passed pointer to NULL, do I have to do it manually after free();?

Comment: @Ned It's going to get considerably more complicated than that. The pointer you need to set to null is the child pointer in the *parent* node (`bt1`'s right node pointer). The pointer `bt3` has nothing to do with your actual tree, other than originally pointing to a node you inserted into it. Frankly, that you're still toting it around is a bad idea. Once in the tree, access should be through the *tree's* referencing pointer. I *strongly* advise you get acquainted with using pointers to pointers. It's near-impossible to write correct tree management code in C without doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Line number 38 on your BinaryTree.c (function `MakeRightSubTree`) should be

`free(main->right);`

instead of

`(main->right);`